# getting error " TypeError: Found non-callable @@iterator " even though the array is inerrable

Tags: javascript, arrays, data-structures, ecmascript-6, destructuring

[image]I'm using one of the online JS editor and it is giving me this below error although when I'm consoling the value of initial it is an array so it should iterate. I' not getting what is wrong with it. Thanks in advance for helping.

```
 let lists = [[1,4,5],[1,3,4],[2,6]];
 let output=[];
 let initial = lists[0]?lists[0]:[]
 output.push(...initial); //giving error here

 for(let i=1; i<lists.length; i++) {
    curr = output;
    next = lists[i];
    j=0;k=0;
    x=0;
    //console.log(j,next,'next')
    while(j<next.length) {
        
        if(next[j]<=curr[x]){
            output.splice(x,0,next[j]);
            j++;
            x++;
        }else{
          if(curr.length>x){
              //k++;
              x++;
          }else{
            output.push(...next.slice(j))
            break;
          }
            
        }
        
     }
  }
 //console.log(output)
```

Comment: What is `lists`? If you mean `list`, how are you making sure that `list` contains what you claim it contains at the time of execution?

Comment: yes lists will be array of array and I'm consoling it as well. and for the given input which i mentioned, it is throwing this error

Comment: So you’re logging a _reference_? Please see [Is Chrome’s JavaScript console lazy about evaluating objects?](/q/4057440/4642212) and make sure that what you’re logging is actually the current state and is not evaluated later. Where does this array come from? Is it asynchronously created? Why do we need to see the `for` loop after the point where the error occurs?

Comment: I'm aware of reference concept, and I'm solving one of a DSA problem where list is coming in input to this function, and I'm giving the input.

Comment: Okay, but the relevant part of this code clearly works. So `lists` is definitely not what you think it is.

Comment: lists is array of array. there might be a usecase where lists[0] is empty but it should never be a single car or digit so for that i have applied the condition and making it an empty array so that is inerrable.

Comment: also this error is runtime error and I'm consoling it just before it is throwing this, so i dont think reference issue will exist here.

Comment: `lists[0]` only checks for [truthiness](//developer.mozilla.org/docs/Glossary/Truthy) via the [conditional operator](//developer.mozilla.org/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Conditional_Operator). _Truthy_ does not imply [_iterable_](//developer.mozilla.org/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Iteration_protocols).

Comment: I tried this too. " let initial = typeof lists[0] == 'object'?lists[0]:[]"

Comment: `typeof lists[0] == 'object'` and _iterable_ are very different things. `Symbol.iterator in Object(lists[0])` is an iterability check.